# hibernate how to order set in hql

Tags: hibernate

I understand if I use

```
  class Fund{
      private Set<FundClass> fundClasses =  new LinkedHashSet<FundClass>();
      @org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy(clause="order asc")
        public Set<FundClass> getFundClasses() {
            return fundClasses;
        }
  }
```

then my FundClasses will be in order, because hibernate use linkedHashset behind the scence. while, if I want to use the order by clause in HQL such as

```
from fund f inner join fetch f.fundClass fc order by fc.name
```

Though the sql returns the records in the order i want, the set is not when I iterator over it, even I define it as linkedHashset. I have a few queries, the fundclass need to be in diffenet order. sometime by name, sometime by order and some other property, I hope I can do the sort in database instead of in memory. how do I do this?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="GP")
    public class GP {

        private Integer id;
        private String name;

        private List<P> ps;
        @Id
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="gp")
        public List<P> getPs() {
            return ps;
        }
        public void setPs(List<P> ps) {
            this.ps = ps;
        }

    }


@Entity
@Table(name="P")
public class P {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    private GP gp;
    private List<C> cs;
    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public GP getGp() {
        return gp;
    }
    public void setGp(GP gp) {
        this.gp = gp;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="p")
    public List<C> getCs() {
        return cs;
    }
    public void setCs(List<C> cs) {
        this.cs = cs;
    }
 }
    @Entity
    @Table(name="C")
    public class C {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    private P p;
    @Id
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    public P getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public void setP(P p) {
        this.p = p;
        }
}
```

the query I run

```
 sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select gp from GP gp inner join fetch  gp.ps p inner join fetch p.cs c where c.age< 5 and gp.name like 'john%'").list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define it to be a `List<FundClass>`. In fact, I think that `Query.getResultList()` returns .. a list.

Comment: I don't think I can use a list, use a list return some duplicates,also, use the list I have the can not get multiple bag simultaneously error.

Comment: You can get around both problems. But I still don't understand how you get a `Set` from an HQL query. Can you show me the code?

Comment: let me explain what I am trying to do, I am not really sure that the good way.  I have grandParent, parent and child, (all one to many), to show a filtered the familiy tree, I have a query like this select gp from grandPanent gp inner join gp.parent p inner join p.child c where gp.name like 'john%' and p.child.age < 5. I want this return me a list of grandParent. I edit the question so you can see the code.

Comment: I want to have 1 hql and hibernate will build a structure (the family tree with only matched grandparent, parent and child) for me intead of 3 query. grandparent first then parent then child. doing this, I have a few problems. if not use list, if I have 1 matched grandparent,which has 2 parents, which has 7 matched child as returning result, I will have 7 grandparent(same one) instead of 1.